# php SMTP connect() failed while sending mail

Tags: php, email

I am trying to use PHPMailer to send e-mails over SMTP but so far I have had no luck. I have gone through a number of questions, PHPMailer tutorials and forum posts but I still cannot find a way to get it to work. I'm still getting an error `Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.`

Here is the code:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Username = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = '************';
$mail->Port = "995";
$mail->From = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Tim Cullen';
$mail->addAddress('james@example.com', 'James Johnson');
$mail->addReplyTo('myemail@gmail.com', 'Tim Cullen');
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Using PHPMailer';
$mail->Body    = 'Hi Iam using PHPMailer library to sent SMTP mail from localhost';
if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}
echo "EMail has been sent!";
//echo 'Message saved to Send folder!';
?>
```

Comment: @Dagon it is still the same, any idea?

Comment: ... Or port `587` if you want to use TLS. http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebgmail. Have you checked your firewall?

Comment: can you connect from the command line `openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465` or windows `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`

Comment: @Dagon I can connect on window telnet so here it is `220 mx.google.com ESMTP gf11sm2923363wic.18 - gsmtp`

Comment: was that using port 587? if so try that in your code

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie how i can check on my firewall?

Comment: @Dagon I am not sure if it is the correct port to use as i'm using gmail.com and not google.com. how i can find out what is the correct port to use? through on setting in my gmail?

Comment: Don't worry about the firewall. If telnet works, then it must be letting you through. Did you try the example I linked from the PHPMailer website? I'd expect that to be a pretty accurate example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try SMTPDebug to see what is actually happening

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

It looks like you're using the wrong port. Try 465 and open that port up.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: here is the debug i get: `2015-03-03 00:14:29 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable (101) 2015-03-03 00:14:29 SMTP connect() failed. Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.`. It sound like to me that it have been blocked from my provider?

Comment: Would you be on shared hosting? Sometimes shared hosting can block SMTP servers.

Comment: yes I am on a shared hosting, so are they block smtp sever?